# Checkbox binding in knockout not working on trigger event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, knockout.js

The checkbox data-binding value is not changing when i try to trigger the click event of checkbox.

I have created a jsfiddle, when i click the button i expect the value bind to change but not.

http://jsfiddle.net/2T9QZ/13/

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling trigger("click") in jQuery simply triggers your "click" event handler(s). It doesn't actually cause a click (and thereby a change of the checked state) on the checkbox - the only time it does something like that is in the case where the element has a function property named the same as the event (e.g. `form.submit()` - but there's no `checkbox.click()`).

But since you're using knockout, you might as well do:

```
var viewModel = {
    IsSelected: ko.observable(false) // Initially false
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


$('#buttonInput').click(function(){
    viewModel.IsSelected(true); // <-------
    // Or, in order to toggle:
    // viewModel.IsSelected(!viewModel.IsSelected());
});
```

That's pretty much the point of using knockout in the first place. Make your changes on the view model, not the view. Since the checkbox's `checked` property is data bound to `IsSelected`, changing `IsSelected` will change the `checked` property of the checkbox.